# Moment.js and the rollup module bundler

Tags: momentjs, commonjs, rollupjs

Is there any way to make Moment.js work with rollup without having to change this `import` statement:

`import * as moment from "moment"`

I tried to use rollup inject plugin but I didn't manage to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

As explained [here](https://github.com/moment/moment), since version 2.10.0, moment is written using ECMAScript 6 modules. The library should therefore be directly compatible with Rollup. Here's a solution using npm :

- Add moment to your node_modules: `npm install moment --save`

To use npm modules with Rollup.js, you need to have these 2 plugins installed in your devDependencies: [rollup-plugin-commonjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-commonjs) and [rollup-plugin-node-resolve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-node-resolve). The first one enables you to use Node's CommonJS modules as if they were ECMAScript modules (= use the `import` syntax to load them).

- Import the module in your code: `import moment from "moment";`

You can now use `moment` normally, for instance:

```
console.log(moment().format());
```

I'm new to Rollup and I've still trying to figure out how things work. I've made a simple test with the solution above and it seems to work, except that the whole library gets included in the bundle — the expected tree-shaking didn't happen and I don't know why.